# Array index out of bound exception for Maximum and minimum program

Tags: java, bluej

I was making a program to accept numbers in double dimensional array and find the greatest and lowest number.
But when I enter mu inputs, it shows error in the 2nd if statement saying:

> "Array index out of bound exception"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DDA_MaxMin
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ar[][] = new int[4][4];
        int a,b,c=0,d=0;
        for(a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the numbers in the matrix "+a+" "+b);
                ar[a][b]=in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        c=ar[0][0];
        d=ar[0][0];
        for(a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<4;b++)
            if(c>ar[a][b])
            c=ar[a][b];
            if(d<ar[a][b])         
            d=ar[a][b];
        }
        System.out.println("The greatest number is "+d);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is "+c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop without `{` will only be valid for next line or next statement.

```
for(b = 0; b < 4; b++)
 if(c>ar[a][b])
    c=ar[a][b]
```

after this `b` value is `4`.

and the if statement after that is out of the for loop hence the out of bounds exception.

Enclose them in braces.

```
for(a=0;a<4;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<4;b++){
        if(c>ar[a][b])
        c=ar[a][b];
        if(d<ar[a][b])         
        d=ar[a][b];
        }
    }
```

Comment: And you should not declare a and b as int when you use it in the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Hey ther you missed the curly brace for the second for the correct code will be

Comment: `for(a=0;a<4;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<4;b++){
        if(c>ar[a][b])
        c=ar[a][b];
        if(d<ar[a][b])         
        d=ar[a][b];
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your second `for` loop which deals with variable `b`. It's missing braces. Change it to:

```
for(a=0;a<4;a++) {
    for(b=0;b<4;b++) {
        if(c>ar[a][b])
            c=ar[a][b];
        if(d<ar[a][b])         
            d=ar[a][b];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ar[][] = new int[4][4];
        int a,b,c=0,d=0;
        for(a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the numbers in the matrix "+a+" "+b);
                ar[a][b]=in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        c=ar[0][0];
        d=ar[0][0];
        for(a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
             if(c>ar[a][b])
               c=ar[a][b];
             if(d<ar[a][b])         
               d=ar[a][b];
                 }
        }
        System.out.println("The greatest number is "+d);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is "+c);
    }`
```

You are missing brackets in the for loop where you are trying to find the greatest and smallest integer.